# Can a person see his family after death?

Tags: atma

Is it possible that a person can see his family after his death? If yes, then how is it logically possible without eyes?

I am not asking for vasanas that a person carries from one birth to another birth.

How is it possible for a person to see what is happening surrounding his body after death?

I believe in rebirth but I feel like it is an automated process and soul dont know what is happening between two births.

While I am sleeping, I cannot see what is happening surrounding me but how a soul can see the surroundings?

I am asking this question because how a soul can enter another person body to fullfill its wishes without having any connection with material world?